# How to scale up a gRPC pub/sub chat service?

Tags: java, kubernetes, architecture, grpc, publish-subscribe

I'm studying how to make a chat service with gRPC. I notice that most of the examples store all the subscriber's connections into a List data structure. When the chatroom got a new message, the server will loop through that List and send new messages.

Stores subscribers in [source code's](https://github.com/Raaaaaaaay86/grpc-chat-server/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/grpcchatserver/observer/ChannelObserver.java) variable **subscribers**.

My question is that when the subscriber number grows up and storing all the subscribers in the HashMap seems like a bad idea because that will cost too much memory? I have tried to store those connections in Redis but it might be impossible [due to the connection is not serializable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848633/how-to-make-grpc-streamobserver-object-serializable-in-java)

My Idea is when I deploy multiple pod instances in Kubernetes. Each chat service becomes independent. How could I get the subscribers correctly when they are distributed on different servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of aspects that I'm thinking:

- Any chat system has some limits in terms of chatroom size. How many subscribers do you want to support? If you want to support tens (or even hundreds) of subscribers, I believe it works well with an in-memory list of subscribers, since it's much faster than having the subscriber's list in an external cache

- When you need to send a message to the entire list of subscribers, instead of looping on that list, you can do that in parallel, using an IO-optimized thread-pool.
- Deploying your chat-service in a pod is a good idea, you need the ability to scale horizontally, but you also need a smart-gateway in front of your service, to route the requests from a given user, to the pod that stores its information (if the subscribers list is stored in memory). Otherwise, if this info is stored externally (in a cache), your chat service can be fully stateless.

Comment: Nice Suggestion. I did come out with a solution to build a smart gateway to route the requests and also implement it just right before you answer. It works. So I can say that the third aspect is possible. But I didn't think about using an thread pool to optimize performance. I will work on it, thanks!